# How to store the value if I run again this vuejs javascript script? script value is again 0

Tags: javascript, vue.js

If I run again this script value will be again 0. I want this component to remember "this. value" How can I keep the last value?

```
data () {
   return {
        value: 0
   }
},
methods: {
   count: function () {
   return this.value = this.value + 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it depends on the scenario in which you want the value to persist.

if only your component is reloading (rerendering) e.g by `v-for` of `v-if` or by `router` you can use [keep-alive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#keep-alive-with-Dynamic-Components) to retain the value. similarly `vuex store` can also be used.

if you want the value to persist even after reloading entire page, you should use [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to store the value.

you can use computed getter and setter to change the value in localStorage like this

```
computed: {
    value: {
        get: () => localStorage.getItem('myCat') || 'defaultvalue';
        set: (v) => localStorage.setItem('myCat', v);
    },
},
```

of course you need to study the localstorage api for pro and cons as localstorage is not reactive.

on the other hand you want the value to be stored on server side then theirs a lot information to be considered, but you can use rest api to get and post value.

Comment: can you please let me know how I can do it as local storage? I want to init value = 0, and change the value = 1. And if I reload the entire page I want value = 1 again and not 0

Comment: did you look at `localStorage` ?

Comment: Storing it on server side means storing in database. you can get and post request to server from client i.e. web browser. But you are asking this question means you dont know much about server side stuff. and it requires in good knowledge of that. Start from which backend you are using as server e.g php, node, ruby on rails etc.